# Multiple counts and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
ID ProductName ProductCode
1  abc         123
2  abc         123
3  abc         456
4  def         789
5  ghi         246
6  jkl         369
7  jkl         369
8  jkl         369
9  jkl         468
10 jkl         468
```

And I wish to create a summary table that looks like this:

```
ProductName ProductCode Total
abc         123         2
abc         456         1
jkl         369         3
jkl         468         2
```

In other words I'm not interested in Products "def" and "ghi" because they only appear once in the original table. For everything else I want to do a group by ProductName and ProductCode and display counts.

I've tried playing about with group by clauses and where in (select...) but I've just ended up going round in circles.

The table has around 50,000 rows and is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is it:

```
SELECT
      ProductName,
      ProductCode,
      COUNT(*) as Total
 FROM Table1
 WHERE ProductName IN (SELECT ProductName FROM Table1 GROUP BY ProductName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 GROUP BY ProductName, ProductCode
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c79ad/9

Answer (score 0):

To filter on an aggregate you need to use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  ProductName,
  ProductCode,
  COUNT(*) as Total
FROM T
GROUP BY ProductName, ProductCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Here is [**a demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c79ad/7) if you wish to use it.

Comment: @jenson-button-event, did I have an equal sign?  Thanks for fixing.  Answering from the phone isn't easy!

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ID, ProductName, ProductCode,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName, ProductCode) AS Total,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName) AS PCount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName, ProductCode ORDER BY ID) AS rn
  FROM Products
  )
  SELECT ID, ProductName, ProductCode, Total
  FROM cte
  WHERE PCount > 1 AND rn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `WHERE` on a column that you are aggregating on.  You need to use `HAVING` instead.

```
SELECT   ProductName,
         ProductCode,
         COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM     Products p
GROUP BY p.ProductName, 
         p.ProductCode
HAVING   COUNT(p.ProductName) > 1
```

Comment: Okay you're right - missed the fact that a single occurrence of both columns should still be included if it is a repeat of the ProductName.